# How do not open JFrame More then one time?

Tags: java, jframe

I am developing one Desktop Application Using Swing. In my application, I design
menu frame, whenever I click one menu_item respective page will load, suppose again I click same menu_item then one more same frame is opened.
But I need only one frame, if already exist then I will show one pop_up dialog to display "Already opened" or to show the frame in front of all opened frame. How can solve this?

Comment: Q: How do not open JFrame more then one time?   A: You don't open the JFrame more than one time.  That's not intended as a joke - that's actually the correct answer!  It sounds like you've got one Swing window, with buttons, and clicking a button opens a new JFrame.  Just define a variable in your "first" window to hold a reference to the "new" jFrame, initialize it to null ... and don't create a new jframe if the variable *isn't* null!  If that doesn't make sense... show us a [MCVE].

Comment: I highly recommend making use of a `CardLayout` and possible a `JTabbedPane` instead